# Crystal Report Issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to arrange my Crystal Report Output as follows

[image: Expected Report]

PC-No, Name in HeaderTable
PC-No, A/C No, Description, Amount in DetailTable

My Report Showing PC-No, Name in top row & A/C No, Discription and Amount in below row(s)

[image: My Report]

I want to know how can i design my Report as shown above

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just reduce the 'Group#2 Name' size or erase and trade it for a label? Then then take the three field you have in details, and put them in GroupHeader #1.